# Sorting a nested List Descending order

Tags: prolog

I have this nested list:

```
Xs =  [ [Joe, Pilot, 100], [Stan, Co-Pilot, 300], [Steve, Pilot, 150],  ].
```

How can I sort this nested list in order to do the following: (Using the third element in descending order)

```
Xs = [ [Stan, Co-Pilot, 300], [Steve, Pilot, 150], [Joe, Pilot, 100] ]. ?
```

Comment: Note that `Joe` is a variable. You need to write `'Joe'` to make it an atom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define:

```
criteria(R,[_,_,N1],[_,_,N2]) :- compare(R,N2,N1).
```

and use "predsort/3" like in:

```
?- predsort(criteria,[ [Joe, Pilot, 100], [Stan, Co-Pilot, 300], [Steve, Pilot, 150]  ], Xs).
Xs = [[Stan, Co-Pilot, 300], [Steve, Pilot, 150], [Joe, Pilot, 100]].
```

If duplicated third elements can exists, "criteria" must be changed. By example as:

```
criteria(R,[_,_,N1],[_,_,N2]) :- N1=\=N2, !, compare(R,N2,N1).
criteria(R,E1,E2) :- compare(R,E1,E2).
```

Comment: `predsort/3` is not a standard predicate. It's a library predicate available in **some** Prolog systems. Answers to **generic** Prolog questions that only work on **specific** systems should not omit those dependencies. Otherwise users of other systems will get the wrong impression on those systems in particular and on Prolog in general.

Comment: According to my information, there are no "sort" predicates in the ISO standard.

Comment: In ISO, there is [`sort/2`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/dtc2#sort) and [`keysort/2`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/dtc2#keysort).

Comment: Thanks, I was looking an older document.

Answer (score 2):

If you change your data representation to structures (which is anyway a good idea), and your Prolog system has `sort/4` (e.g. [ECLiPSe](http://www.eclipseclp.org/doc/bips/kernel/termcomp/sort-4.html), [SWI](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=sort/4)), you can simply do:

```
?- Xs = [emp(joe, pilot, 100), emp(stan, copilot, 300), emp(steve, pilot, 150)],
   sort(3, >=, Xs, Ys).

Xs = [emp(joe, pilot, 100), emp(stan, copilot, 300), emp(steve, pilot, 150)]
Ys = [emp(stan, copilot, 300), emp(steve, pilot, 150), emp(joe, pilot, 100)]
Yes (0.00s cpu)
```

A more portable (ISO) method is to pair each list element with a sorting key, then use keysort/2, then strip the keys again:

```
?- Xs = [emp(joe, pilot, 100), emp(stan, copilot, 300), emp(steve, pilot, 150)],
   add_keys(Xs, KXs),
   keysort(KXs, KYs),
   strip_keys(KYs, Ys).

Xs = [emp(joe, pilot, 100), emp(stan, copilot, 300), emp(steve, pilot, 150)]
KXs = [-100 - emp(joe, pilot, 100), -300 - emp(stan, copilot, 300), -150 - emp(steve, pilot, 150)]
KYs = [-300 - emp(stan, copilot, 300), -150 - emp(steve, pilot, 150), -100 - emp(joe, pilot, 100)]
Ys = [emp(stan, copilot, 300), emp(steve, pilot, 150), emp(joe, pilot, 100)]
Yes (0.00s cpu)
```

using the auxiliary predicates

```
add_keys([], []).
add_keys([Emp|Emps], [Key-Emp|SEmps]) :-
    Emp = emp(_Name,_Job,Salary),
    Key is -Salary,
    add_keys(Emps, SEmps).

strip_keys([], []).
strip_keys([_-V|KVs], [V|Vs]) :-
    strip_keys(KVs, Vs).
```